# Replace a string which ends with space using regex

Tags: c#, regex

Below is my sample code
Here i need to match a word Franchise with space at the end and need to replace only the word which ends with space

Pattern : string with space at the end, should replace one 'Franchise ' with space at the end.

```
string pattern="Franchise ";
string textboxvalue= "'All Franchises', **'Franchise '** &amp; First(Fields!FranchiseLabel.Value, 'DigitalPanelList'))";;

Regex.Replace(textBoxValue, pattern,"hello" )
```

Comment: Replace by which? What is `lstElem`?

Comment: Does this work? What is your question?

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you use [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method ? This is such a simple operation.You do not need `Regex` for this.

```
textboxvalue = textboxvalue.Replace("Franchise ", "hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

use the function of string :

```
EndsWith(String)
```

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith(v=vs.110).aspx